# Access SQL format DateDiff hh:nn:ss

Tags: sql, ms-access, datediff

Using Access 2010

I'm trying to take the difference of two datetime entries and display that value in the format "hour(s):minute(s):second(s)". I have the following SQL statement but it always produces: "00:00:00". What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT TOP 500 
    [ID], 
    [USERNAME], 
    [TIME_ENTER], 
    [TIME_EXIT], 
    FORMAT ( 
      DATEDIFF("s", [TIME_ENTER], [TIME_EXIT]),  "hh:nn:ss"
    )  AS HH_MM_SS
 FROM tbl_logs_sessions;
```

The `[TIME_ENTER]` and `[TIME_EXIT]` columns are set to "Date/Time" and the Format is "General Date"

Comment: "s" is for second which will return the difference in second in number.. instead just do normal subtraction and format the date result.. vba.Format(#11:00:10# - #23:00:00#,"hh:mm:ss") =  11:59:50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATEDIFF` returns a number than cannot be converted to "hh:ss:ss" as its not a date.

Instead:

```
FORMAT(DATEADD("s", DATEDIFF("s", [TIME_ENTER], [TIME_EXIT]), #00:00:00#), "hh:nn:ss")
```

Note that if the difference exceeds 24 hours you will wrap around back to midnight.

Comment: This is perfect. The user won't be in longer than 24 hours so Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
FORMAT([TIME_EXIT] - [TIME_ENTER], "hh:nn:ss") AS HH_MM_SS
```